# Is working in orchard like workout in gym?

Tags: muscle, strength, workout, health, heart

I have recently bought an small orchard and I work there time to time. Like shoveling pruning etc. Is this good for my health and muscles like gym?

My purpose is not to build big muscles. I just want a better vascular system and a little bit more strength in my muscles.

Comment: Physical activity is good for your health, but comparing the physical activity expected in a gym to that of an orchard doesn’t make sense. Also, if you want to get stronger then you’ll need to challenge the specific muscles that you are wanting to get stronger.